# Phaser3 Rotation Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a simple animation effect of a pendulum swinging back and forth. I'm only using a single image sprite for it, and I've got the code below, but the animation only tilts to a 45 angle then stops completely. What might I be doing wrong?

```
    var title = new Phaser.Scene("GameTitle");
var pendulum;
var direction;
title.create = function(){
    pendulum = this.add.sprite(200, 0, 'titlePendulum').setOrigin(0.5, 0).setScale(1.8).setRotation(79);
    direction = "left";
};

title.update = function(){
    console.log(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0));
    swing(direction);
    if(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) == 71){
        swing ("right");
    }
    if(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) == -76){
        swing("left");
    }
};

function swing(dir){
    if(dir == "left"){
        if(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) == 71){
            swing("right");
        }else{
            pendulum.angle +=1.5;
        }

    }else{
        if(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) > -80){
            pendulum.angle -= 1.5;
        }
        if(pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) == -76){
            swing("left");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but why are you updating `swingInc++` for each update() frame? You are checking swingInc<4 so it will only update for 4 frames? Where do you reset swingInc to zero?

Comment: I was originally trying to run the animation 4 times, not realizing it was incrementing by frame. I've tried a couple of things since, and have come up with the current code in the post, however, same problem. It tilts to the angle specified and then just stops.

Comment: I've edited my answer, you may want to look at that `dir` and `direction` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you check if the `pendulum.angle` is larger than or exactly equal to 80 in two separate `if` statements. However 80 is not divisible by 1.5, and the value of the angle could be `.. 76, 77.5, 79, 80.5 ..` and the condition `pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) == 80` will never be true.

Also, the name of the function parameter is `dir` but you check for a `direction`.

I'm pretty sure that is causing the problem. Even if that's not it, it's still better (more elegant and "cleaner") to use `if-else` when you are checking for a condition that can either be one thing or the other, instead of using two separate `if` statements.

So change your code to something like this:

```
function swing(dir) {
    if (dir == "left") { // check parameter, not the direction global var
        if (pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) < 80) {
            pendulum.angle +=1.5;
        } else {
            swing("right");
        }
    } else { // dir == "right"
        if (pendulum.angle.toFixed(0) > -80) {
            pendulum.angle -= 1.5;
        } else {
            swing("left");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the dir variable. I've updated the code in the post again to reflect the current setup. I've noticed something interesting, though. As I adjust the target angle at which to reverse the swing, the angle at which the pendulum is also adjusting. When set at 79 degrees, the pendulum shoes to have stopped at 76. When I adjusted to 76, it changed and stopped at 74. Setting it to 74 caused it to stop at 73, and so on. No idea what might be causing this.